# access external hard drive to delete folder on terminal Mac

Tags: command-line, osx, external-hdd

I want to delete a folder of portable hard drive on terminal in Mac. Are there any command line ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to **unmount** (that is, no longer show the portable hard drive as being connected) or to delete a folder **on** the portable harddisk?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `rm` to remove the folder on your external hard drive.

The full Terminal command looks like this

```
rm -r /Volumes/$drivename/$folder
```

Replace `$drivename` with the name of your external hard drive.
Replace `$folder` with the name of your folder.

If you don't know the name of your external hard drive you can look it up with

```
ls /Volumes
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of which folder to find the external hard drive under :)